# Looking for log monitoring and remote copy mechanism

Tags: logging, apache-spark

I have a large Spark cluster (80 machines), and I am having problems running my jobs (on big data sets).
In order to debug this, I need to see what's going on in terms of the Spark logs in every machine, particularly errors.

Currently I need to ssh to each machine (they are GCE machines), and look at the specific file there. This is not scalable, and I am looking for a better solution.

I would like to have kind of an agent on each machine, that tracks a certain root folder, and once every X minutes, copies all files under it to some remote location (GCS).

Is there such existing framework, or do I need to invent the wheel here?

Comment: You could use [Salt](http://www.saltstack.com/). Salt just lets you run the same command over a set of machines. So you would basically ask salt to execute your command you use to download the logs on all the servers. The salt command could then be added as a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) or [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) can do the job to collect logs to central location (e.g., Elasticsearch). You can see the logs in Kibana, Hive (HDFS) or something else. Although both agents' functionalities are similar, I suggest to use Fluentd as it's becoming so popular these days that Google adopted it to its default cluster log collection in Google Clould Platform.

Logging Pods in a Kubernetes Cluster using Fluentd, Elasticsearch and Kibana
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/contrib/logging/fluentd-ek/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used something simple. I set a cronjob in all workers that triggers a file copy to a bucket in the cloud. This way, the bucket contains all the log files from all locations. However, I did not need salt in this case, since I pre-installed the cron job in all workers, using a startup script for all those GCE machines.